# How to name class name according to Java Generics type return?

Tags: java, class, generics

```
< T > T foo(P p) {
  ...
}
```

I'll get different types of return from foo according to the parameter I inserted, which means T changes according to p.

Then I try to call this function and use its return result.

**Class** x = foo(p);

What should I write in substitute of Class here?

Suppose parameter is a enum type.

```
enum P {
   XX,YY,ZZ
}
```

then the return type T is Xx, Yy, Zz respectively according to parameter.

Let me give the exact sample here.

```
public <T> List<T> getProperty(Property property) {
  switch(property) {
  case NAME: List<Name> names = new ArrayList<Name>(); 
      names.add(this.name); return (List<T>) names;
  case PHONE: return (List<T>) this.phones; 
  case EMAIL: return (List<T>) this.emails;
  case ADDRESS: return (List<T>) this.addresses;
  case NOTE: List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
      notes.add(this.note); return (List<T>) this.note;
  default: return null;
  }
}

public enum Property {
  NAME, PHONE, EMAIL, ADDRESS, NOTE
}

public List<Entry> search(Property property, String s) {
if(this.isEmpty()) {
  return null;
}
List<Entry> result = new ArrayList<Entry>();
for(Entry e : entries) {
  if(e.getProperty(property) != null) {
    for( **Object** p  : e.getProperty(property)) { //What should I write instead of Object
      if(p != null) {
        if(p.containString(s)) { //there'll be errors if use Object. Need to know p's class.
          result.add(e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
return this.nonDuplicatedResult(result);
```

}

Comment: Where is `foo` defined?  In a generic class?  Where is the code `Class x = foo(p);`?  In another method of the generic class or from another class's method?

Comment: It would be the type T used when the class with foo() is defined.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I would suggest changing your implementation to fit the following signature or some variation of it:
`<T<? extends P>> T<P> foo(P p)`

Comment: This makes sense, but the thing is enum type are not exactly the same as class name... do you suggest that I change the enum so that each value is not all Capitalized?

Comment: It sounds like `P` should not be an enum at all, and should have a generic type argument `T`.  Having the enum name correspond to class names is just going to be a huge, fragile mess.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you're asking.  You haven't explained your use cases at all and haven't given us much code to look at.  It's difficult to provide useful feedback from within the fog of obfuscation.

Generally speaking, if you want a method that returns a different object depending on the value of a supplied argument, then what you're probably talking about is a static factory method which can return any object that is a subtype of the method's return type.  It is convenient to make such objects a part of an interface-based type system (eg. the static factories for the EnumSet class).

The use of an interface-based type system is actually necessary if you wish to return an enum, because enums cannot be part of a class hierarchy, but they can implement an interface that forms an interface-based type system.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose parameter is a enum type.

```
enum P {
   XX,YY,ZZ
}
```

> then the return type T is Xx, Yy, Zz respectively according to parameter.

No it isn't. The return type is P. You're over-thinking this. The 'enum' case isn't a job for Generics at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an finite number of return types, you could just check through each one using instanceof to see if the returned value is of a certain type. So in this case **Object** would substitute class, then you could later cast it.

Comment: What if the parameter p is a enum type

Comment: That doesn't seem like a problem to me.. Just pass in whatever enum you want and handle the return like I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is basically with that method definition, what you are saying to the compiler is that your method will return whatever the parameter assignment declares itself to be. You can do that, but how your method is implemented will boil down to a compiler warning, as you can't actually ensure that you are generating the appropriate type - since you don't know it, it is never passed to the method, and erased at compile time.

More typically what you would do is:

```
<T extends P> T foo(T p) {
    ...
}
```

Now you get an object of the right type as a parameter, so you have some idea of what to return. That concept has little utility with enums, though.

Here is a real world example of where you could use the method definition you posed in your question:

```
    public static <T> T generateProxy(Object realObject, Class<?>... interfaces) {
        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(realObject.getClass().getClassLoader(), interfaces, new SimpleInvocationHandler(realObject));
    }
```

Of course such a method generates a compiler warning. Now, what you are saying here is that the caller will define a variable, and will be sure to pass in at least one interface of the type they define. If they don't, they will end up with a ClassCastException at runtime, but you avoid calling code that knows what it is doing from explicitly casting.

It is debatable if that is a good idea.

So the short answer is that you can define the Class to be whatever you want - the compiler will accept anything - but if the method doesn't return the correct type, you will get an exception at runtime, so it is all about how you implement the method. Rarely can a method be smart enough to return the right thing without the correct type as a parameter. And if you can't pass in an appropriate parameter declared with the generic type to the method, you will have to deal with a compiler warning in order to return anything (other than null).